# Simple Web app styled CMS, but having problems with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-applications, content-management-system

I building a simple, 7 page, database driven, website, and I would like to build a simple CMS for it. A super simple CMS just for changing the text on certain pages and uploading images to another. I wouldn't even go as far as to call it a CMS. I mostly doing it for the learning experience of building a web app.

What I was thinking, is using php to build a simple web page that would have some simple login handling. Then use ajax to load the different modules for each page. Like on the main page I would like only the text to be changeable. What I thought I could do was use ajax to load another php page that just loads up a tinymce editor and preloads it with the text that is in the database, with a simple ajax button to upload the text to the database. Similar to a iframe but with out the iframe.

When I attempted this all I got was some text and textarea box. Turns out it only loads text not javascript. upon further reading I found out I could use eval to transform the text loaded into javascript, but this leads to scope issues from what I understand.

So I'm basically wondering how do I do this my goal is something similar to google and/or yahoo mail apps. I thinking at first I could throw all the javascript code I'm going to use on the main page and just load content with ajax, but from what I have read the javascript won't apply its self to the new code since it wasn't there when the code was applied to the DOM elements sometime when the page first loaded. My next thought was to load the content then load the script using jquery and apply it to the newly loaded content, but attempting to find anything on that was confusing at best.

Has anyone done anything similar to this and is willing to share what they learned, or just know what I'm talking about and can help me out? Or is the solution simple and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: I guess should of added that I already built the backend cms out of php. Using tinymce as the editor. I'm not having problems with that. What I want to do is convert this into a web app for the experience. I'm have problems loading modules (I guess that's what they would be called) in to the page as needed. To give it the web app feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a little more detail (like code, procedures, etc.) however, i'd like to help out.

regarding the tinymce, here's my take on it:

- create a php file that has timyMCE on it. let's name it "tinymce.php"
- create a php file that loads the text in the database. let's call it "defaulttext.php"
- on your main page (app page), load "tinymce.php" via ajax. this loads the tinymce editor from the php file to the main app page
- create a callback (a function call after success of a previous procedure) after "tinymce.php" has loaded. in this call, call "defaulttext.php" and load it's contents to the textbox of the "tinymce.php" contents loaded earlier.

in all, there is 2 calls: a call for the editor and after it, the default content.

You can use preloaded scripts to do what is needed before loading any content. create scripts to handle DOM, events, etc (event handlers).

Comment: As I have said I have already built the backend out of php, but thanks anyway. The problem with the preloaded script is that code such as new buttons, a new instance of tinymce, and all that fun javascript stuff isn't being applied to the newly downloaded html injected code.

Comment: are you using any javascript libraries like jQuery? in jQuery, there is the function .html() that parses the returned javascript along with the html returned. it sort of functions like eval() at some point, evaluating scripts mixed in the HTML returned.

Comment: I am using jQuery's ajax functions to load the data into the div. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Thank you,that worked with my simple tests. Which means I was breaking something with my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. You don't need AJAX to build a simple CMS. Just ad support for handling a query parameter such as ?edit=true to your pages. When the server receives that, dish out the page into an editor that supports code editing, such as EditArea. To save, simple HTTP post the data back to the server and store it back into the DB or even better, directly back on disk. If you did this right, you could wire it up to directly edit the php files for each page. And yes, lots of people have done this :) Good luck.

Comment: Actually I have already created a php based backend and it does everything I need it to do, so thats not the problem. What I am try to do is learn how to make web apps and do it this way because, I believe this is a good learning experience.